# Integrate GCC 4.4 with NetBeans on a Mac

Tags: c++, gcc, netbeans, c++11, macports

I've got **NetBeans 6.9** installed on a Mac OS Snow Leopard. Also, I installed **gcc 4.4** through MacPorts in order to experiment with C++0x.  I believe, by default NetBeans uses the standard Apple **gcc 4.2** compiler which is invoked through a `g++` symlink found in `/usr/bin`.

My question is: how can I still use the new compiler?

I tried creating a new *Tool Collection* in NetBeans by specifying the default directory to `/opt/local/bin` which is where gcc 4.4 is present. But this caused error messages, i.e. **No compiler sets were found...**. I also tried modifying the existing **GNU** Tool Collection by selectively specifying the C++ Compiler command as `/opt/local/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin10-g++-mp-4.4`. However, this caused build errors which I didn't even understand. Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe here, adding a new tools chain with that path, just **should** work with gcc 4.4, see here http://forums.netbeans.org/post-70004.html
Are you sure nothing is missing in your GCC 4.4 ?

The only missing step is to click "Reset Settings" help in Code Assistance tab after creating the tool chain, to make sure that code assistance picks the new headers.

Comment: Thanks, but what you describe doesn't apply to me. I don't experience any Code Assistance related problem. I cannot add a new Tool Collection with `/opt/local/bin` being its working directory.

Comment: Yes I know, but I wanted to show this message proves what you're doing ought to work, down to the specific gcc version. So if it breaks, it's not that you are not doing the correct thing, rather that something is broken in your install, even if I don't have a specific idea what.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

Create a directory for your toolchain:

```
mkdir -p ~/toolchains/gcc-4.4-mp/bin
```

then link gcc's binaries into the bin directory

```
cd ~/toolchains/gcc-4.4-mp/bin
ln -fs /opt/local/bin/*-mp-4.4
```

and give gcc's tools their unmodified names back:

```
for x in *-mp-4.4 ; do ln -fs $x ${x%-mp*} ; done
```

or

```
for x in *-mp-4.4 ; do mv $x ${x%-mp*} ; done
```

Now you can add `~/toolchains/gcc-4.4-mp/bin` as a new *Toolchain Collection*.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the "easiest" solution. Edit your `PATH` environment variable and then open NetBeans.

```
sudo port install gcc_select
sudo gcc_select mp-gcc44

# tcsh:
setenv PATH /opt/local/bin:${PATH}

# bash:
PATH=/opt/local/bin:${PATH}; export PATH

# And then:
open /Applications/NetBeans.app
```

You should be good to go after that unless NetBeans (uses an absolute path to the compiler).